# Is it possible to use toString on undeclared object?

Tags: java, object, tostring

I want to print "None" value for undeclared objects instead of null. Is it possible?

```
public class class1 {
    class2 c2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class1 c1=new class1();
        System.out.println(c1.c2);

    }
}
class class2{

    public String toString(){
        if(this==null){
            return "None";
        }else{
            return "Correct";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I have added the code. This code prints:

```
null
```

But I want to print "None". What should I do?

Comment: What is an "undeclared object"? Variables are declared, not objects. Do you mean a reference variable without an assigned reference? Please show your code and clarify your question.

Comment: My mistake sorry, i mean, private Weapon weapon; I want to print "None" for weapon.

Comment: Again, please post your code and clarify your question. This sounds like a possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you may be barking up the wrong tree, where the solution to your underlying problem is completely different.

Comment: Note you can [edit] your question to add more information, including a [mre].

Comment: Think about it this way - of the infinite number of class2 instances that do not exist, how will the compiler determine which one to call with a null 'this' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility class [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) offers a lot of useful methods. There's for example `Objects#toString(Object)` and `Objects#toString(Object, String)`.

```
final String s = Objects.toString(obj, "None");
```

---

After your edit: the `this` reference is never null, therefore `this == null` will always be false. You need to handle the null-check outside of your class. Normally, `String.valueOf` will be called when converting an object to a string. This method handles `null` references, not the class itself. You'd have to manually convert your object to a string first (with the utility described above).

You'd need to change your code:

```
public class Class1 {
    Class2 c2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        System.out.println(Objects.toString(c1.c2, "None"));
    }
}
class Class2 {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
            return "Correct";
    }
}
```

You can always create a wrapper around `Objects#toString(Object,String)` to avoid specifying the default value over and over again:

```
public final class MyObjects {
  private MyObjects(){}
  public static String toString(final Object obj) {
    return Objects.toString(obj, "None");
  }
}
```